# Tablet for treadmill

Tags: health, furniture

I think of using a tablet to play or work while walking a treadmill. The treadmill's has a dedicated place for an mp3 player, ipod or a tiny smartphone only . I have 10 inch tabled with a base, and 13 inch one converting into a laptop with an attachable keyboard, and not yet sure which one will work best with treadmill.

I think attach an unused Vesa monitor stand to a wall or furniture and then glue loop and hook tapes to the stand and tablets.

Or should I rather buy a designated tablet gooseneck? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Consider velcro tape. Stick the soft side on your tablet/laptop and the 'catchy' side on a part of the treadmill. I have done for my phone on my car dash and it works like a charm.

You will have to consider the weight of the tablet, and have a protective cover in case it falls off.

If your equipment is expensive, consider the gooseneck for peace of mind.